Suitelt 2.0 Sublist Name shows unwanted behavior
In NetSuite Suitelet Development, sub-list labels often become clickable links due to the default system behavior. We want to display these labels as plain text without any link functionality. Is there any way to achieve this? We don't want the right-click window as shown in the screenshot to appear or It should be simple plain text.Screenshot
We tried different sublist types but we can't use them because we want sublist lines to be editable.

Post your suitelet code.

What problem is this causing for your users?

As this might be not best practice, but I think it will help. To remove the clickable behavior of sublist labels in NetSuite Suitelet ,you can add a hidden inline HTML field with a script tag that enforces CSS to disable the pointer effect (i.e., cursor: default) for the specific sublist label class.
More details steps that may help:

Inspect the sublist element:

Right-click the sublist label in the browser and select "Inspect" (or use browser DevTools).
Identify the class of the label that has the link behavior.


Add a hidden inline HTML field in your Suitelet:
Use form.addField to create an inline HTML field that injects custom CSS and JavaScript. The script will modify the style of the sublist label by changing the cursor to default and disabling link behavior.


Code Snippet:
...
let inlineHtmlField = form.addField({
    id: 'custpage_hidden_html',
    type: serverWidget.FieldType.INLINEHTML,
    label: 'Hidden HTML'
});

let inlineHtmlField = form.addField({
    id: 'custpage_hidden_html',
    type: serverWidget.FieldType.INLINEHTML,
    label: 'Hidden HTML'
});

// Set the script in the inline HTML field content
inlineHtmlField.defaultValue = '<script>' +
    'document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {' +
    '    var sublistLabels = document.querySelectorAll("THE_CLASS_NAME_TO_BE_UNCLICKABLE");' + 
    '    sublistLabels.forEach(function(label) {' +
    '        label.style.cursor = "default";' +  // Set cursor to default (remove pointer)
    '        label.removeAttribute("href");' +   // Remove link behavior
    '    });' +
    '});' +
    '</script>';
...

